# ValueError: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [395, 1] in Linear Regression

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, scikit-learn, linear-regression

I have been getting an error in this simple Linear Regression, can someone tell me what's wrong?
I have heard that reshaping the array helps, but Don't exactly know what it means

```
import sklearn 
from sklearn import linear_model
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
import numpy

data = pd.read_csv("student-mat.csv",sep= ";")

data =data[['G1','G2','G3','studytime','failures','absences']] #all attributes we want to take into consideration

predict = "G3" #label which we wanna predict FINAL GRADE

X = numpy.array(data.drop([predict],1)) #removing G3 from the dataset as that is our dependent variable Y

y = numpy.array([predict])#predict is G3, which we wanna predict. G3[FINAL GRADE] depends on  stduytime, failure,etc

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X,y,test_size = 0.1) #see COMMENTS BELOW

linear = linear_model.LinearRegression()

linear.fit(X_train,y_train)
acc = linear.score(X_test,y_test)
print(acc)
```

I am just getting the accuracy of the model right now, so that explains the `linear.score` command

Comment: `y = numpy.array(data[predict])` ?

Comment: Using X axis for the dependent variable (G1,G2,studytime, etc....) And Y axis as independent variable which I want to predict. As you can see predict variable is containing "G3" which is the final grade. I am using the popular student-mat.csv from uci